# Eigen ConjugateGradient solver not running multithreaded

Tags: multithreading, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

I have a sparse matrix A of size (91716x91716) with 3096684 nonzero elements, and a dense vector rhs. I am solving the system with a ConjugateGradient this way:

```
initParallel();
ConjugateGradient<SparseMatrix<double>, Lower|Upper> solver;
solver.compute(A);
const VectorXd response = solver.solve(rhs);
```

I'm compiling with:

```
g++ -O3 -I./eigen -fopenmp -msse2 -DEIGEN_TEST_SSE=ON -o example example.cpp
```

The executions, both with multi-threading and without, take approximately the same (around 1500 ms).
I am using Eigen version 3.2.8.

Is there any reason why the multi-threading is not performing better? I actually don't see the multithreading effect in my system monitor. Is there any other way to accelerate this process?

Edit:
A call to Eigen::nbThreads() responds 12 threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document of the version 3.2.8

> Currently, the following algorithms can make use of multi-threading: general matrix - matrix products, PartialPivLU

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html

---

As dev document mentions more algorithms are using multi-threading, you need to change to Eigen3.3-beta1 or development branch to use the parallel version of ConjugateGradient.

Comment: Oh, I guess I was confussed because of this: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicMultiThreading.html

Comment: Which one is the newest version?

Comment: Your document is newer, but you need to use the dev branch

Comment: Im using the latest version (stable), but I wouldn't mind to try the development version if I could find where to download it.

Comment: eigen front page, just below the download link to the version 3.2.8